# OptaPlanner: Issue Optimizing Vehicle Routing by Passing Problem as a Parameter

Tags: spring-boot, optaplanner

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am working on optimizing a vehicle routing problem using OptaPlanner ins Springboot, and I've encountered a challenge when attempting to pass my problem instance as a parameter(the parameter contains demo data) to the solve method. Unfortunately, the optimization process is not yielding the expected result and throws "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solutionClass (class org.acme.vehiclerouting.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution)'s entityCollectionProperty (field private java.util.List org.acme.vehiclerouting.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution.vehicleList) should never return null".

Here's a detailed summary of the issue:
Objective:
I aim to optimize a vehicle routing problem by passing my problem instance as a parameter to the solve method in OptaPlanner.

Issue Faced:
Despite passing the problem instance, the optimization process is not producing the desired result. The solution does not reflect the expected improvements in the vehicle routing.

Expectation:
I expect the solve method to optimize the vehicle routing problem based on the provided problem instance, producing an improved solution.

- I have Verified the contents of the solver configuration XML file (optaplanerConfig.xml) to ensure it accurately represents the problem requirements.
- Confirmed the presence of appropriate  and  elements in the configuration.
- Reviewed scoring rules and constraints to ensure they accurately represent the business rules of the vehicle routing problem.
- Temporarily simplified scoring rules to identify whether they might be causing the issue.
- Confirmed that the solver termination conditions in the  element are appropriate for the problem.
- Adjusted termination conditions based on the problem requirements.
- Enabled debug logging in OptaPlanner to gain more insights into the optimization process.

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or corrections to help me understand why the optimization is not working as expected. Thank you for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

The error message can not be any clearer:

```
The solutionClass (class org.acme.vehiclerouting.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution)'s 
entityCollectionProperty (field private java.util.List org.acme.vehiclerouting.domain.VehicleRoutingSolution.vehicleList) 
should never return null
```

Your vehicle list is `null` and it must not be.
Make sure the field `VehicleRoutingSolution.vehicleList` has a non-null value, typically an empty list for an uninitialized solution, and you're all set.

Also, to get support for the latest Spring Boot and much more, consider [migrating to Timefold Solver](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork).